# rails Nokogiri click all buttons with same tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am trying to scrap a web page that requires a click in order to display a phone number (https://homestars.com/on/toronto/electricians?page=1). 
I can access and click on the 1st button using

`browser.button(class: "company-search-contact__button").click`

But I can't acess the following ones given that they all have the same tag.
I have not found any variations of the button() method that can be more specific.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question. Nokogiri has no way to "click" a button. Perhaps you're talking about Mechanize, which uses Nokogiri under the covers and does know about `click` and `button`.

Comment: Well i am able to perform the first click without having the Mechanize gem.    I thought there was a way to do this without having to deal with mechanize, and there is, except as Amit Patel mentionned ; the website uses Captcha

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for providing this clarity. This took me a surprisingly long time to figure out that Nokogiri doesn't click stuff. We ended up using Watir that using Selenium Driver under the hood for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are using would only click on first button. You need to select all buttons and click them one by one

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://homestars.com/on/toronto/electricians?page=1"))

buttons = page.css('button.company-search-contact__button')  #select all buttons on the page
buttons.each do |button|  # for each button
  button.click  #click on the button
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: With this solution the 'button' element becomes unclickable Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (663, 21). Other element would receive the click: <div class="site-header__inner">...</di
v>

Comment: The site is protected from unauthorized access using Captcha.

Comment: Alright thank you, is there different method perhaps a different framework through which i can do this ?